# Intel MKL multi-threads computing with Rcpp

Tags: r, parallel-processing, rcpp, blas, intel-mkl

I changed R's default BLAS to intel MKL and gains sufficient speed improvement. On my PC, MKL uses 4 threads. Now I tried to parallel my code with `snow` in R. In order to avoid the conflicts between two levels of parallel computing, I used `setMKLthreads(1)` to limit MKL only using one core. But when I was runing my code, by checking Windows task manager, all CPUs are involved.

```
#If I run some test example, like 
setMKLthreads(1)
set.seed (1)
m <- 10000
n <-  5000
A <- matrix (runif (m*n),m,n)
system.time (B <- crossprod(A))

setMKLthreads(4)
system.time (B <- crossprod(A))

setMKLthreads(2)
system.time (B <- crossprod(A))
```

More cores will run faster, and the Windows task manager correctly reflects the number of cores involved.

But why `setMKLthreads` didn't work in my case? I started to wonder if it's related to my package built using Rcpp/RcppArmadillo. I am wondering if `setMKLthreads` can control C++ level code or not? Since the task manager still gives me full CPU usage. Then I tried to recompile my package after setting `setMKLthreads(1)`, and it didn't work as well.

If my guess is correct, how can I change the C++ level MKL in order to limit to 1 core?

I add a small example here: first is the C++ code:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat cross_cpp(arma::mat A, arma::mat B){
  arma::mat C=A*A.t();
  return(C);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat cholesky_cpp(arma::mat A){
  arma::mat C=arma::chol(A);
  return(C);
}
```

And in R:I generated a positive definite matrix with 6000 rows, and doing a cholesky decomposition. While for this example, there is no difference in time. But my point is that if you can monitor the CPU, you will find that no matter how many cores I set for MKL, it will always boost up to the maximum. In my case, I have 4 physical cores and 8 logical cores, and the CPU usage boosted to 50% in both cases. What I'm expecting is that when I limit it to 1 cores, the maximum CPU usage will be 12.5%.

```
library(clusterGeneration)
B = genPositiveDefMat(dim = 6000)
setMKLthreads(1)
getMKLthreads()
time1 = Sys.time()
C <- cholesky_cpp(B$Sigma)
time2 = Sys.time()
time2-time1

setMKLthreads(4)
getMKLthreads()
time1 = Sys.time()
C <- cholesky_cpp(B$Sigma)
time2 = Sys.time()
time2-time1
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Rcpp(Armadillo). R itself would call the same matrix multiplication functions.  The topic is not new and has been discussed a few times; you should find something in the r-sig-hpc list archives.

Comment: Thank you! I think I've found the post you mentioned. It's for OpenBLAS on Linux, but some keys words in the post can help me do more searches. I think using `#define ARMA_DONT_USE_WRAPPER` before RcppArmadillo is included will make the compilation using the basic BLAS. However, I need to figure out how to use MKL (just because i'm on a windows machine) with only one core for the compilation.

Comment: That may not be the post in had in mind -- and generally speaking, and as also stated numerous times, you do _not_ need to recompile when switching BLAS.  These provide an API; different versions are interchangeable.